# User Account Creation: adding to database, retrieving and displaying

Tags: java, jsp, session, model-view-controller, cookies

I am curious about how it works when a user is trying to create an account on a website. Does the website use a session or cookie or even MVC to create the account, store it in the database?

I am not sure if session is too much to use for user account creation which includes certain validations (e.g. password needs to be of a complexity). Or would a cookie be sufficient?

I have read the following post but am still not sure on how to go about it to be efficient in my coding.

[Session or cookie confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16099752/session-or-cookie-confusion)

[Differences between cookies and sessions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359434/differences-between-cookies-and-sessions)

Note: I am using eclipse and Tomcat 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do by :

1/ creating a jsp page (view) where you put a form for user

2/ creating a java class(model) where you put a method that connect to database and insert data  (example NewAccount(String username,String password,...){...})

3/ create a servlet(controller) to get data (name , password ...) from the form and pass it to the model by calling a method

Comment: I am guessing you are using the MVC?

Comment: must i use a servlet?

Comment: if you are using jsp you it's recommanded to work with it as a controller

Comment: Do you have any resource on a servlet? I have seen many guides online but they are pretty vague or too complicated

Comment: You mean tutorial ?

Comment: this is an example of login(MVC) :
http://www.javatpoint.com/MVC-in-jsp