# user authentications via session or cookies?

Tags: php, session, authentication, session-cookies

This moment if user enter's correct username and password i just simply creating session:

```
$_SESSION['userid'] = $user_data[0]->id;
$_SESSION['username'] = $user_data[0]->username);
$_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
```

After that, with $_SESSION['loggedin'] i can check if user can view part of website or not.

Is this method 'good/safe' ?

- Any benefit's using cookies based and session based authentication ?
- Which method most common site's using ?
- What you guys using for your sites ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this great answer from Joel Coehoorn on this page .
Most of your questions are answered in this post.

[Web authentication state - Session vs Cookie vs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356562/web-authentication-state-session-vs-cookie-vs)

I hope this will help.

Cheers

Comment: Actually that answer is a bit misleading. You can hijack a session by stealing cookies (and threat can be danger depending upon how session is implemented).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any framework, then most framework comes with authentication library.

And for other purposes you can use phpseclib (a security library....). Its still in beta stage. I have tried it. Sounds promising.