# I want to restrict access to certain web directories through URL

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am doing project using zend framework-2. I want to restrict access to certain web directories through URL(if user without log in). if user tried to log in I need to redirect login page. this is what I do(rough idea not codes ).

AuthController

```
 if(username and password ok){
     setcookie('username', $username);
     setcookie('password', $password);

     //redirect to AlbumController indexAction
     return $this->redirect()->toRoute('album', array('controller' => 'album', 'action' => 'index'));
  }
```

so within AlbumControoler I added this code

```
public function indexAction()
{        
    if(isset ($_COOKIE['username']) && isset ($_COOKIE['password'])){
        //some codes
    }
    else{
        //if user not logged redirect to loogin page 
        return $this->redirect()->toRoute('auth', array('controller' => 'auth', 'action' => 'index'));
    }
}
```

so if I use this way I need to add above codes every action. so my question is is this way ok? or is their easy way to do that?

Comment: Never go with Cookies in Username/Password format. Not only can cookies be created manually (I'd be able to easily gain accesss to your web-app), but also are they a huge security risk like this! Check out [ZfcUser][1] and [ZfcAcl][2]

  [1]: https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser
  [2]: https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcAcl

Comment: @Sam can I use session instead of cookies

Comment: You need to learn about the differences. See following questions for some insights: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356562/web-authentication-state-session-vs-cookie-vs and as far as ZF2 is concerned the above mentioned modules will do quite a bit for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

As an answer for the actual question, you can do it in your controllers construct... something like this...

```
namespace Application\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController {

    public function __construct() {
        $session = new \Zend\Session\Container('auth');
        if ( !isset($session->name) || !is_string($session->name) ) {
            echo "The following is not set:".$session->name; 
            header('Location: /user/login');
            exit();
        }
    }
```

But as the previous posters noted cookies are really bad to use for something like this.  This is a very generic example although the exit(); part is pretty important in this sense as you want to kill the script to not show any data in case the user hits escape on their browser.  The exit(); will essentially kill out and not display anything.